# Q: Calculating Fourier Coefficients and Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

Let $\Omega >0$ and $x \in \mathcal{B}_{\Omega/2}$ is continuous.  Define $\hat{y}(\omega) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb Z} \hat{x}(\omega - n\Omega)$.

If $\hat{y}$ is expressed as

\begin{equation}
\hat{y}(\omega) = \sum_{k \in \Bbb Z} a_ke^{2\pi i k \omega/\Omega}
\end{equation}
calculate the coefficients $a_k$.

Show that

\begin{equation}
\hat{x} =\begin{cases}
    \hat{y} & \text{for } |\omega| < \Omega/2\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

and calculate the values of $x(t)$ by the inverse Fourier Transform.

---

**My Attempt/Input**

I know this problem is related to the Whittaker-Kotel'nikov-Shannon Sampling Theorem in some manner. I also know that to calculate the coefficients, I can use the equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Omega} \int_{-\Omega/2}^{\Omega/2} f(t) e^{-i2\pi k \omega/\Omega} dt
\end{equation}

However, I don't quite get what $f(t)$ is here.

Comment: I guess $f(\omega)$ should be $$f(\omega) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb Z} \hat{x}(\omega - n\Omega)$$

Comment: I am still confused as to how I would be able to get coefficients from that.  All of the Fourier Series problems I had dealt with in the past gave a very explicit function that had an obvious integral associated with it.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with signal processing.

Comment: Also posted on dsp.SE

Comment: Yes, I posted it on both sites to reach a wider audience.  Is this frowned upon?  If so, I apologize as I was unaware and will remove one of them.